# How do I avoid timeouts and get Apache2 to start at system startup?

Tags: apache2, startup, services

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with the default install of Apache, in which I configured a virtual directory.  I would like to run Apache as a srevice, that automatically starts when the system reboots.  I noticed Apache wasn't running upon system restart and then noticed this

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
[sudo] password for davea: 
[....] Starting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
davea
```

I wasn't sure what it meant so I tried getting the status as recommended above ...

```
$ sudo systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2021-01-18 19:00:16 UTC; 4min 33s ago
  Process: 800 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Jan 18 18:58:47 prod systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 18 18:58:47 prod apachectl[800]: Invoking 'systemctl start apache2'.
Jan 18 18:58:47 prod apachectl[800]: Use 'systemctl status apache2' for more info.
Jan 18 19:00:16 prod systemd[1]: apache2.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 18 19:00:16 prod systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jan 18 19:00:16 prod systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I'm still unclear what else I need to do.  I'm able to restart Apache without any problems using

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 2607:f298:5:101d:f816:3eff:feac:4c03. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Not sure why there is a warning or if I shoudl be concerned about it but I defined the "ServerName" in my conf file below

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf
```

What else do I need to do to get Apache to run as a service upon system startup?

**Edit:** In response to comments, here's configtest and journalctl output immediately after restarting ...

```
$ sudo apachectl configtest
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 2607:f298:5:101d:f816:3eff:feac:4c03. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK

$ sudo journalctl -xe
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Jan 22 01:36:35 prod systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1001.
-- Subject: Unit user@1001.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit user@1001.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Jan 22 01:36:35 prod systemd[1028]: Reached target Default.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Jan 22 01:36:35 prod systemd[1028]: Startup finished in 219ms.
-- Subject: User manager start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The user manager instance for user 1001 has been started. All services queued
-- for starting have been started. Note that other services might still be starting
-- up or be started at any later time.
-- 
-- Startup of the manager took 219137 microseconds.
Jan 22 01:36:55 prod systemd-timesyncd[565]: Synchronized to time server [2001:67c:1560:8003::c8]:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jan 22 01:37:03 prod sudo[1172]: davea : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/davea ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Jan 22 01:37:03 prod sudo[1172]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by davea(uid=0)
```

**Edit 2:** Contents of /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service after attempting suggested answer ...

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-abort
TimeoutStartSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Rebooting still fails to start Apache.  However, when I manually run "sudo apachectl restart" that starts things up.

Comment: Is `000-default-le-ssl.conf` actually being used by Apache? What configuration files do you see in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`?

Comment: Yes.  I know it's being used b/c I'm able to visit https://mysite.com ("le" stands for LetsEncrypt, an initiative to get free HTTPS certs)

Comment: The output of journalctl -xe is missing..

Comment: And "sudo apachectl configtest" is of course = Syntax OK..

Comment: As LarsJoo as suggested, could you update your question to include the output of `journalctl -xe` after Apache fails to start on reboot? It would also be helpful to see the output of `sudo a2query -s`, which will list all enabled confutation files. With this, it may be possible to begin providing specific suggestions to resolve the two issues outlined in your question 

Comment: @Matigo, I added the output as requested by you and Lars . Let me know if there's anything else I can include.

Answer (score 2):

The Apache service generally has a window of 90 seconds to start. If it cannot do so during boot time, `systemd` will kill the process and report it as timed out. Under most circumstances, Apache can be started (and restarted) in well under a second, but it can get stuck behind a dependency during boot time if there is another process that requires additional time. I have seen this on occasion when the network interfaces take a little longer than usual to start up, or when the system is waiting for a response from an NTP server to synchronise the internal clock.

One of the simplest ways to reduce the frequency of this error is to increase the service timeout value from `90` to something a bit higher, like `180` or `300`.

Here is how you can do this:

0. SSH into the server
1. Open the `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service` file with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service
   ```

   ***Note:** If you do not have a file at* `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`, *then the configuration file will be at* `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d/apache2-systemd.conf`.
2. In the `[Service]` section, add this line (Press <kbd>I</kbd> to Insert/Edit):

   ```
   TimeoutStartSec=300
   ```

   Feel free to set the `TimeoutStartSec` value to something you're comfortable with, but do keep it above 90. Otherwise the timeouts at boot will continue.

   Once done, you should see something like this:

   ```
   [Service]
   Type=forking
   Environment=APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true
   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
   ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop
   ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
   PrivateTmp=true
   Restart=on-abort
   TimeoutStartSec=300
   ```
3. Save the file (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>)

At this point, you can reboot the server and see if Apache continues to time out. Please note that this is not solving the crux of the problem, which is the extended time required to boot, but it should enable Apache to start up after all the init processes are complete.

#### Bonus Fix

To eliminate the `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name` messages, you can set a default for the system. This will not affect the performance of the web server in any way:

0. SSH into the server (if not already connected)
1. Open the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```
2. At the very bottom of the file, add this line (Press <kbd>I</kbd> to Insert/Edit):

   ```
   ServerName 127.0.0.1
   ```
3. Save the file (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>)
4. Test the Apache configuration files for errors:

   ```
   sudo apachectl configtest
   ```

   You should see:

   ```
   Syntax OK
   ```

Now you can either restart Apache with a `sudo service apache2 restart` or, if you're doing this after updating the `TimeoutStartSec` value, you can reboot the server.

Comment: Hi, Added the complete /etc/apache2/apache2.conf as an edit to my question.  Still not getting Apache to start when rebooting.

Comment: @Dave edit */lib/systemd/system/apache2.service* and change `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment` to `Environment=APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true` as shown in Matigo's answer  ( no need for `TimeoutStartSec=300`. remove it ) then run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` after that run `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service` and it should work.

Comment: I gave this a try but although Apache does seem to run after system reboot, the Python application connected to it (through mod_wsgi) no longer works because it is not finding expected environment variables.

Comment: @Dave Oh I see. In this case do both ... first `Environment=APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true` then in the line after it `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment` and all should work fine.

Comment: Dear @Dave and Matigo, After looking at the answers here and searching the internet I have seen many questions like this but no solutions were provided anywhere I looked that address this issue directly. Given the above, I wrote an answer that is to the best of my knowledge direct and to the point. Hopefully you will find it helpful. Best regards

Comment: Cool. Hope that resolves the issue 

Answer (score 0):

[To enable a service](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/systemctl.1.html#commands) to start on boot run:

```
sudo systemctl enable <serviceName>
```

Comment: I ran "sudo systemctl enable apache2", then restarted.  No dice.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked on our sister site **Unix & Linux**:

- [Services timed out at boot but could start manually what could be the problem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412996/services-timed-out-at-boot-but-could-start-manually-what-could-be-the-problem)

In that answer the solution was changing the file `/etc/systemd/system.conf`  and the two lines:

```
#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s
```

On my machine it is 90 seconds but on the linked answer it was 15 seconds which was too short. If your says 15s then change it to:

```
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s
```

Note removing the `#` turns the line from a comment to a command.

Also note your `journalctl -xe` doesn't appear to have the apache2 related errors? You probably need to press <kbd>Page Up</kbd> a few times. Alternately you can try using `journalctl -b-0` instead and using  <kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simple and yet vital.

There is an **execution environment variable** missing in your **systemd** apache2 unit file AKA "apache2 service file" ie. `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`

This variable is `$APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD`. It must be set and it goes under the `[Service]` section AKA [**systemd.exec** or **Execution environment configuration**](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#)

This variable can be set like so:

```
Environment=APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true
```

This variable is required for Apache to start and run correctly after [Apache's integration with systemd since Apache version 2.4.42 and later](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_systemd.html). It provides **systemd** with handling and reporting capabilities of `/usr/sbin/apachectl` and the `apache2` process.